# Display how many people viewing my website

Tags: javascript, html, symfony-1.4

How can I display how many people are currently viewing my website? Is there any script I can use for this? I am developing my web on Symfony 1.4. it supposed to displayed on Home page i mean the number of current viewer.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought:

```
<?php
Class ClassNameHere {

    ....

    function echo_counter() 
    {
        if ($sessionString = $this->get('cache')->fetch('session_ids')) {
            $session_ids = unserialize($sessionString);
        } 

        if (!isset($session_ids))
            {   
                $session_ids[time()] = session_id();    
            }
        elseif (!in_array(session_id(), $session_ids)) 
            {
                $session_ids[time()] = session_id();
            }


        $lifetime = 60 * 3; // 3 min

        foreach($session_ids as $time => $session_id) 
        {
            if ($time < time() - $lifetime) 
                {
                    unset($session_ids[$time]);
                }
        }

        $this->get('cache')->save('session_ids', serialize($session_ids));

        echo 'We have '. count($session_ids) .' open sessions';
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Does symfony do something really odd to `$_SESSION`? Surely that can't count the number of open sessions because `$_SESSION['ids']` would be unique *per* session.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Mad the same with caching

Comment: Question is count user (can be not registered visitor) and display it in symfony 1.4 :\

Comment: Sarnai Enhmandah, go on... what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider an Ajax script?! You could run an ajax script just before the page have been loaded, and then recheck if the user is still on the page...

Comment: let me search about ajax counter :)

Answer (score -3):

The best and easiest way to analyze the site visits real-time by yourself is to use [Google Analytics](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.google.lk/analytics/&ei=LaF7Ub-eEsSmrAevgIGACA&usg=AFQjCNHSXs7bWqb2tF_sEfkU0yhN6Xu_CQ&sig2=abLpKF6rGPtMHol0k7l-HA&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk). With the real-time events report, you can now not only see the top events as they occur but also filter on particular event categories (and actions). Additionally, you can see whether particular segments of visitors trigger different events and debug your events deployment in [real time](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/03/4-improvements-to-google-analytics-real.html).

If you want visitors to see the real time picture then better use any of the real time web counters you can find.

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't provide a way to show that data.

Comment: Noe google has enabled a nice and detailed real time analysis. http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/03/4-improvements-to-google-analytics-real.html

Comment: I think the question is asking about displaying the data to visitors and not having them in a private account.